PROC SQL CASE statement to check multiple variables in different rows and columns
I'm asking this because I'm not actually sure if this can actually be done.
The data is organised in the following format



ID
year
type




1
2023
A


1
2024
B



I'm trying to check these conditions under PROC SQL with CASE statement:

If type = B and year = 2024 and type A's year is <= 2024 then 'TRUE'
else 'FALSE'

I've tried to a few case statements but my main struggle around is I'm not sure how I can check specifically the year of type A?
My less elegant solution is to store all Type = B and Year = 2024 in a separate table and cross check that with a separate table that stores Type A's year.
In the sample data above, the conditional check should produce a TRUE value.
I would appreciate it someone would point me in the right direction or perhaps suggestions some functions.
Thank you.

Do you mean this: if the current record has type = B and year = 2024 and there is another record with the same id that has type = A and year <= 2024 then true else false?

Hello SAS Newbie, welcome to StackOverflow. Please react to the comments and answers. We do our best to help you and expect your follow-up.

If you use left join to create table like this:
ID    YEAR    TYPE    YEAR_IN_CORR_ID_AND_TYPE_IS_A
1     2024    A       2023

You can use case statement easily.
proc sql;
  select a.id, a.year, a.type,
    case when .<b.year<=2024 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as result
  from your_data as a
  left join your_data as b on a.ID=b.ID and a.type='A' and b.type='B'
  ;
quit;


The condition is: the current record has type = B and year = 2024 and there is another record with the same ID that has type = A and year <= 2024.
proc sql;
  select unique ID
        ,ifc(T1.ID='' | T2.ID='', 'False', True') as RESULT length=5
  from TAB 
         left join 
       (select unique ID where TYPE='B' and YEAR =2024)  T1 
         on TAB.ID=T1.ID
         left join
       (select unique ID where TYPE='A' and YEAR<=2024)  T2  
         on TAB.ID=T2.ID
 ;



If type = B and year = 2024 and type A's year is <= 2024 then 'TRUE'

These Statement has a logical mistake if i understand you correkt. You would need an OR between those two, otherwise it can't be true.
I would start with a block of data that shows me the results for debug and that work with this data to get the expected results.
 /*--HAVE DATA*/
%let autoformatBlock =;
data work.MyOldData;
    infile datalines delimiter= '#';
    input ID year type $;
    datalines;
1# 2023# A
1# 2024# B
2# 2023# A
2# 2025# B
3# 2025# A
3# 2024# B
;
run;

/*--STATEMENT RESULTS*/
%let autoformatBlock =;
proc sql noprint;
    create table work.TmpData as
            select
                base.*
                ,(case
                    when (
                        (
                                (lower(base.type) in ('b'))
                            and (year = 2024)
                        )
                        or (
                                (lower(base.type) in ('a'))
                            and (year <= 2024)
                        )
                    )
                        then 'true'
                    else 'false'
                end)        as 'Hit'n
            from work.MyOldData as base
            group by
                base.ID
    ;
quit;

/*--WANT DATA - Only IDs that match Statements Results true*/
%let autoformatBlock =;
proc sql noprint;
    create table work.MyNewDataResult as
        select
            res.*
        from work.MyOldData as res
        inner join (
            select
                *
            from (
                select
                    ID
                    ,count(ID) as 'Anzahl'n
                from work.MyOldData
                group by
                    ID
            ) as base
            inner join (
                select
                    ID
                    ,count(ID) as 'Anzahl'n
                from work.TmpData
                where (Hit = 'true')
                group by
                    ID
            ) as tmp
                on (
                        (base.ID = tmp.ID)
                    and (base.Anzahl = tmp.Anzahl)
                )
        ) as want
            on (res.ID = want.ID)
    ;
quit;


I think you have misunderstood the question. The condition is: the current record has type = B and year = 2024 and there is another record with the same id that has type = A and year <= 2024.

i think that is the right way to go. with these results you can start to work ;) ... i updated the code to show all blocks

You will need to join the data with itself in order to evaluate criteria that involves other rows.
Is the actual problem the following:
For a given ID, for the type in the latest year, are there any prior years with a different type? Or should it be 'the 1 year prior'? What is there is a prior year with a gap of 2 years?  In an ID has multiple years, should the type of each year be evaluated with respect to its prior years?  Formulating good criteria for the desired result set will lead to better solutions.
